# Cannot get a selected text or value in ComboBox

Tags: c#, wpf

I have a combox in my wpf application with three items:

```
<ComboBoxItem Tag="some value">Text</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem Tag="some value2">Text2</ComboBoxItem>
<ComboBoxItem Tag="some value3">Text3</ComboBoxItem>
```

I want to get a selected text or value at runtime. When I do this:

```
myComboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()
```

it returns this:

```
System.Windows.Controls.ComboBoxItem: Text2
```

How can I get a selected text or value?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because you want the `Content` property of `ComboBoxItem` you should try like this:

```
(myComboBox.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem).Content.ToString();
```

Or for `Tag`:

```
(myComboBox.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem).Tag.ToString();
```

Answer (score 1):

you need to cast the SelectedItem property of the Combobox to the object, then you can access the properties. So in your case you need to cast it to ComboBoxItem.

Comment: ((YourType)comboBox.SelectedItem).YourProperty

Answer (score 0):

You just need to get the tag from the object.

```
<ComboBox SelectionChanged="Selector_OnSelectionChanged">
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="some value">Text</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="some value2">Text2</ComboBoxItem>
    <ComboBoxItem Tag="some value3">Text3</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>

    private void Selector_OnSelectionChanged(object sender, SelectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        var cb = sender as ComboBox;
        if (cb == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var selectedItem = cb.SelectedValue as ComboBoxItem;
        if (selectedItem == null)
        {
            return;
        }

        var tag = selectedItem.Tag;

        Debug.WriteLine(tag);  
    }
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<ComboBox Name="comboBox" SelectedValuePath="Content">
  <ComboBoxItem>text</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>here</ComboBoxItem>
  <ComboBoxItem>text</ComboBoxItem>
</ComboBox>
```

Get the value

```
 var value = comboBox.SelectedValue.ToString()
```